How to add SoundClip of a Speaker in NLAEditor using python
I want to automate playing a sound via speaker multiple times.
I know that there is a operator bpy.ops.nla.soundclip_add to add soundclip to a speaker.
But it's an operator and need some context setup like active_object, ...
Is there any direct pyhton API to iterate then add SoundClip to the speaker like python API in VideoSequencer here is a VideoSequencer example:
sequences: SequencesTopLevel = context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences
    # Iterate through the sequences and delete them
    for sequence in sequences:
        # a: Sequence = None
        if sequence.channel == 1:
            sequences.remove(sequence)
        sound_strip = sequences.new_sound(
            name = name,
            filepath = "C:/Users/Mahdi/Desktop/a.mp3",
            channel = 1,
            frame_start = 30
        )


Could you please edit your question to focus on a specific problem? For instance, instead of asking "Is there any direct Python API to iterate, add, remove SoundClip" which includes multiple questions and might be closed for lacking focus, try asking something like, "How do I add a sound using python?" This will help ensure your question is more precise and easier to address. Please read How to ask a good question for more information.

at first glance I see a big problem, you're removing a sequence while iterating over the sequences list. I suggest you don't do that
